# JavaScript Date Difference - one hour too much

Tags: javascript, html, date

I'm pretty new to JavaScript, but I've got an issue.
I have a HTMl5-Page with 2 input elements of the type `time`.
I want to get the difference between the two times, so that 11:15 and 12:00 would give me 0:45.

I think the HTML is pretty straight forward:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <label>Anfang: </label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="time" id="begin" required="true">
    </li>
</ul>

<ul>
    <li>
        <label>Ende: </label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="time" id="end" required="true"></li>
</ul>
```

Nothing special here I guess. In my JavaScript, I attach a listener to a button which fetches the value of these two fields and passes it to the following function to create date objects out of the time:

```
function timeToDate(input) {
    var hours = input.substring(0, 2);
    var min = input.substring(3, 5);

    var date = new Date();
    date.setHours(hours);
    date.setMinutes(min);
    return date;

}
```

to get the difference, I do:

```
var beginDate = timeToDate(begin);
var endDate = timeToDate(end);
var diff = endDate.getTime() - beginDate.getTime();
var b = new Date();
b.setTime(diff);
console.log(b.getHours());
```

So, but the console output for 11:00 (beginDate) and 12:00 (endDate) is **2**, but it should be 1, or am I not getting the clue here?

Comment: to != too, sorry for the grammar patrol but I couldn't help myself.

Comment: I'm sorry, english is not my first language. Nevertheless, you're right - just a typo!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`setTime()` takes a number of milliseconds **UTC**.

`getHours()`, on the other hands, prints the hours in your local timezone.

The *"one hour too much"* you see, when you print `getHours()` is your time offset from UTC.

You would have the desired hour using `getUTCHours()`.

I'm assuming you're using this algorithm only to compute a `hours:minutes` representation of a small positive date difference. Then it's fine. Simply don't try to apply this to bigger duration computations.

Comment: `getUTCHours()` will not work, either, if the timespan is longer than 24 hours or when there are leap seconds, etc. near that time. The problem is that `Date` is just that - a date and not a timespan.

Comment: @Sebastian I assume OP only uses this in very specific cases.

Comment: Reading the API of JS would be helpful :-) thanks for this advice, very logical. Nay, this is not for longer computations, just a little time track app

Comment: @sebastian in this case the time span is not allowed to be vigger than 10

Answer (score 2):

Using `setTime()` is error-prone - since what you are actually setting is milliseconds since January first 1970 in UTC time.

Using `getHours` will yield the *time of the day* in *your time zone*, which is likely to be different than UTC time.

You will see this if you set the time to 0 - `getHours()` will not necessarily yield 0.

Also you will get wraparound effects, so if your time delta is longer than 24 hours you will get a value modulo 24. 
So in order to calculate the difference between two dates in hours, I suggest you use regular maths instead:

```
var hours = (diff/(1000*60*60))|0;
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the Date object can be used with a time offset. With your code `diff` contains the number of milliseconds between the two times. You can get the number of hours from this by dividing by 60*60*1000:

```
var hours=diff/(60*60*1000);
```

This can result in fractions though, for example a difference of 15 minutes would be 0.25 hours. If you need full hours, you can round up or down with `Math.ceil()` or `Math.floor()`, for example:

```
console.log("Full hours: "+Math.ceil(diff/(60*60*1000)));
```